# Str object is not callable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ecab93a49f0c> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 dt=pd.read_csv("/content/survey_results_public.csv")
      3 dt

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

import pandas as pd
dt=pd.read_csv("/content/survey_results_public.csv")
dt
```

Comment: Restart your notebook and start clean. You must have overwritten `pd.read_csv` with something like `pd.read_csv = ...`.